# Creating a nested JSON from a value in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm very new to Django and the DjangoRest Framework and this is my first question on Stack overflow, please bear with me.

I am trying to create a Django Rest API that can that to handle entries for an online raffle. So each entry would have details like name, email, and a string that represents the raffle entry in the form of numbers separated by spaces(Eg: "12,23,34,45,56,67").
So far, I've been able to do the basics and create a simple model, serializer, and views.

What I need is to create a JSON similar to

```
{
    "entry" : "12,23,34,45,56,67",
    "name" : "SampleName",
    "email" : "sample@sample.com",
    "values" : [
        "one" : 12,
        "two" : 23,
        "three" : 34,
        "four" : 45,
        "five" : 56,
        "six" : 67
    ]
}
```

models.py

```
class EntryModel(models.Model):
    entry = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=17)
    name  = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(null=False)
```

serializers.py

```
class EntrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = EntryModel
        fields = ['entry', 'name', 'email']
```

views.py

```
class EntryViews(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = EntryModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EntrySerializer
```

Comment: where are you getting values list? is it from other model?

Comment: Given the fact you already have the information in "entry" you shouldn't need it in "values". Now to do what you want, take a look at https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#listfield

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you want the `entry` field to be expanded into `values` field.

In serializer, you can use a [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield).

```
class EntrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    values = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = EntryModel
        fields = ['entry', 'name', 'email', 'values']
    
    def get_values(self, obj):
        #here object is the EntryModel instance, you can access the entry field with obj.entry, transform into required format and return
```

Comment: Thank you!. I think this might just do it.